# Night mode issue on UIWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I made some kind of a reader which uses an UIWebView. I'd like to include a Night Mode function which colors the text white and the background black, instead of normal black text on a white background.

For this I use the following code:

```
if (nightMode == YES)
{
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    NSString *setJavaScript = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.webkitTextFillColor= 'black'; document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].style.backgroundColor= 'white'; DOMReady();"];
    [readerWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:setJavaScript];
    [readerWebView.scrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:(NO) forKey:@"nightMode"];
    nightMode = NO;
}
else
{
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    NSString *setJavaScript = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.webkitTextFillColor= 'white'; document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].style.backgroundColor= 'black'; DOMReady();"];
    [readerWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:setJavaScript];
    //[readerWebView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]]; // doesn't solve it
    [readerWebView.scrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:(YES) forKey:@"nightMode"];
    nightMode = YES;
}
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Most of the times this works find and I get the result I expected. But sometimes it looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

The margins that are set in the UIWebView remain white when should be black, or black when they should be white. This seems totally random! Especially because it's not on the whole webpage but it starts at 1024px down (exactly, the height of the iPad screen).

Does anyone have any clue how to fix this?

It's both in the simulator and on a real iPad.

Comment: Have you tried calling [readerWebView setNeedsDisplay]?

Comment: Doesn't help, unfortunately

Comment: Is that happening in simulator or actual device? There maybe a bug with simulator ... that's just a guess

Comment: It's on both the simulator and actual devices...

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming this i HTML content here). You are going at this problem from the *outside* of the `UIWebView`, I think you need to inject the inversion logic *into* the web view. I'd suggest you instead inject CSS that inverts the content (as describe e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6903292/288672)). The downside for you would be that if you don't already know CSS you will have to learn at least some of it, and inverting won't exactly be easy. But should end up with a much lower amount of problematic edge-cases that are due to difficult to control implementation details in WebKit (that are also in a quit high risk of changing in future versions) that might be too difficult to find out.

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you mean, I think I am using the stuff described in your link, right? And I am familiar with CSS and I actually alter the CSS with DOM, only it's totally random where it does or doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

- You can use this code also for day & night mode. This code may be work for as your need.
- This will properly work for `UIWebView`.

The code is:

```
BOOL isNightMode;

- (IBAction)nightModeBtn_click:(id)sender {
    isNightMode = YES;
    [self.webView reload];
}
- (IBAction)dayModeBtn_click:(id)sender {
    isNightMode = NO;
    [self.webView reload];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)_webView{
  if(isNightMode == YES){
    [self.webView setOpaque:NO];
    NSString *setJavaScript = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@" document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.webkitFilter='grayscale(100%%)';document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].style.webkitFilter='grayscale(100%%)'; DOMReady();"];
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:setJavaScript];
  }
}
```