# UIWebView loadHTMLString sometimes does not load or apply CSS and JS

Tags: javascript, ios, css, uiwebview

I have an infinite carousel made of `UIWebView`s. On every swipe, one `UIWebView` gets removed (ARC) and one gets built. On the main thread, the `UIWebView`s are populated with html by calling `loadHTMLString:baseURL:` on the `UIWebView` instance.
Most of the time it works as expected: the html gets its layout from **css-** and **js-scripts**. But sometimes it fails and the html is presented without styles. (Sometimes it is shown with styles but without fonts loaded with @font-face.)
**css-** and **js-** files definitely exist and are to be found in the folder offered under **baseURL**.
It seems that this behaviour occurs more often on iPad3 and more recent devices than on older devices. And it occurs more often on building the whole carousel than on pure swiping.

**UPDATE:** Usage of `loadData:MIMEType:textEncodingName:baseURL:` instead of `loadHTMLString:baseURL:`seems to reduce unexpected behaviour. I'd appreciate any hint in which direction to look for the bug.

Comment: I'm struggling with this problem too, have you found a solution to this? Would appreciate your insight!

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could try is loading the HTML first, and when the page has rendered, inject the stylesheet and JS scripts programmatically using [UIWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString *)string]. [This question has good examples of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6903292/uiwebview-css-injection-using-javascript?rq=1). This will at least let you break the issue down, one step at a time.